# French corpus with frequency list of POS tagged words (not lemmas)

Tags: corpora, french

I'm trying to find a corpus (even purchase it) of French language that has these characteristics:

- It should has a frequency list
- List of words (not just lemmas) which are POS tagged
- Preferably taken from diverse fields

Very similar to [COCA in English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).

Of course searching through Google can give many links. But none has them all. And besides, my French is not that good to understand website contents. I truly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a high Google result that I’ve come across before, though I have not used it myself. It seems to satisfy your requirements: [Lexique](http://www.lexique.org), based on [FRANTEXT](https://artfl-project.uchicago.edu/content/artfl-frantext).

Answer (score 0):

Entering the query string `french corpus pos` into the [Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu/search?1) gives you some choices, including *PAROLE* and *Corpus arborée du français*.